# Connected components in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

Given:

```
arr = np.array([
   [0, 1, 2],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [2, 0, 0]
])
newarr = csr_matrix(arr)
print(connected_components(newarr))
```

How the output look like this?

```
(1, array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: Where's the question? Did you ask something or are you explaining it?

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear to you. It looks like that because that's what the `connected_components` function returns.

Comment: Did you expect to get different output? What did you expect?

Comment: I didn't understand the the theory behind the output.